# Should you exclude node_modules from a Webpack build Node.js server in production for best performance/minimal hardware usage?

Tags: node.js, webpack

When working with Webpack it is often adviced to exclude node_modules from the build for improved performance.

What is best used in production for the best performance and/or hardware usage;

1. Excluding node_modules (with the node externals plugin for instance) in the Webpack config and running `npm install --production` to install the required modules on the server before starting the Node.js server.
2. Not excluding node_modules in the webpack config. Letting webpack compile everything into a single file which you start on the server.